# Seeking Collaborators for Unpaid AI-HCI Field Research: Strategies and Platforms

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate, collaboration, networking, group-dynamics

Is there a practical approach or platform to find unpaid undergraduate or graduate students interested in collaborating on AI-HCI field research studies? I'm looking for enthusiastic individuals who want to gain experience and contribute to the field, but I'm unsure how to reach out or where to look. What strategies or online communities can I leverage to connect with potential collaborators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a fruitless quest unless you are at a large university with an established program in the field. Both undergrads and graduate students have their own issues and tasks that must be dealt with. Few are willing to work without any composition if it to be added to other necessary tasks.

At a large university you could start a working group and advertise locally (with other professors) about the topics of interest in the group.

Unless you are an advisor in a degree program you have little to offer.

If you publish widely in the field it is just possible someone will find you with a request to collaborate if they are looking for a research problem. But even then you'd have to coordinate with their university advisor to make this possible.

You might find other professors with similar interests at conferences if you use the time between talks fruitfully. A lot of informal idea sharing goes on at some of them. The "coffee/snack area" can be pretty productive.